# Sequelize index already exist error appearing when I run application

Tags: javascript, node.js, indexing, sequelize.js

I created this migration file:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.createTable('note_tags', {
      id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
      },
      note_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
          model: 'notes',
          key: 'id',
        },
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
      },
      tag_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
          model: 'tags',
          key: 'id',
        },
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
      },
    });
    await queryInterface.addIndex('note_tags', ['note_id']);
    return queryInterface.addIndex('note_tags', ['tag_id']);
  },

  down(queryInterface) {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('note_tags');
  },
};
```

Now when I run my application I get this error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeDatabaseError: relation "note_tags_note_id" already exists
```

The index does exist in my local database. I'm not sure what to do as I have something similar for `supplier_users` but with a `supplier_users_supplier_id` index but never get this issue.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted the index from the database and restarted the application.